# Why is my namespace not detected?

Tags: docker, iproute, namespace

I tried form home,then `sudo su -`

```
ip netns exec 5bd337503b01 ip addr show
Cannot open network namespace "5bd337503b01": No such file or directory
```

pwd shows

```
/var/run/docker/netns
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run` so it doesn't really matter which is written below. I'll use `/var/run` for Docker and `/run` for `ip netns`.

`ip netns` mounts network namespaces in its dedicated `/run/netns` directory. Docker uses a different dedicated directory `/var/run/docker/netns`, so `ip netns` has no knowledge of anything Docker-related and vice versa. Both tools are not meant to manipulate pseudo-files provided by the user nor make these pseudo-files available. The user provides names or hashes and is not supposed to mingle with these mountpoints directly: this is implementation detail in both tools and is not something to be considered a public API. Nevertheless...

What can be done is "duplicate" (with a bind mount) the mounted network namespace to have it also appear in `/run/netns/FOO` thus making it available with `ip netns exec FOO ...` and `ip -n FOO ...`

One can:

- With a recent enough `ip netns` version having the `attach` sub-command

  Use a running container's PID as reference to mount the PID's namespace (available through `/proc/PID/ns/net`) elsewhere. Below simply reuses the container's name which differs from the network namespace mountpoint name. This can be programmatically done using `docker inspect` and the correct JSON filter.

  ```
  ip netns attach containername $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)
  ```

  To use the same name as the network namespace as named by Docker rather than the container's name, one can use (at least today) `.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey` which has a value of `/var/run/docker/XXXXXXXXXXXX`.

  ```
  ip netns attach "$(basename "$(docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey}}' containername)")" $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)
  ```
- with an older version of `ip netns` that doesn't support `attach`

  Create at least once a *netns* namespace to have proper configuration done (eg: `/run/netns` is created as a mountpoint with shared propagation):

  ```
  [ ! -e /run/netns ] && { ip netns add dummy; ip netns delete dummy; } # for correct initial setup
  ```

  Create an empty file and mount the namespace from the PID reference retrieved from `docker inspect` over it:

  ```
  touch /run/netns/containername
  mount --bind /proc/$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)/ns/net /run/netns/containername
  ```

  Or with the variant to reuse Docker network namespace name rather than the container name:

  ```
  touch /run/netns/$(basename "$(docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey}}' containername)")
  mount --bind /proc/$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)/ns/net /run/netns/$(basename "$(docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey}}' containername)")
  ```
- or simply directly without the use of a process PID nor `docker inspect`

  For example to make all currently visible Docker's mounted network namespaces available to `ip netns`:

  ```
  [ ! -e /run/netns ] && { ip netns add dummy; ip netns delete dummy; } # for correct initial setup

  for i in /var/run/docker/netns/*; do
      netnsname="$(basename "$i")"
      touch /run/netns/"$netnsname"
      mount --bind "$i" /run/netns/"$netnsname"
  done
  ```

Such namespaces made available through `ip netns` won't disappear until the references from both Docker and `ip netns` (using `ip netns delete somenetnsname`) are removed. The use of `ip netns delete somenetnsname` should be done for proper cleanup and won't affect this network namespace because it's still in use by Docker: it just removes a mountpoint reference to it and  until all references are removed, nothing happens.